# What relationship do I need here?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm creating small CRUD web app. I'm in problem because I don't know which relationship I should use and how to create that tables. I want to have two tables, `employee` and `employee details`. An employee can have one detail and one detail can have one employee. That is one to one right?  How to create that sql and mapping in Java? Also, I want to auto set `employee_detail_id` in `employee` table, so in `employee_detail` table column `id` will be same as `employee_detail_id` in table `employee`. I'm trying like this:

`sql:`

```
 use `etsystem`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employee_detail`;

CREATE TABLE `employee_detail` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `work_experience` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hobby` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `nationality` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employee`;

CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_detail_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_DETAIL_idx` (`employee_detail_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DETAIL` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_detail_id`) REFERENCES `employee_detail` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

`Employee` entity:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="employee_detail_id")
private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;
```

`EmployeeDetail` entity:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="employeeDetail",
        cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.REFRESH})
private Employee employee;
```

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you did it wrong from the start.

`employee_detail` should reference `employee`, not vice versa. Employee table is a *master* and it has a primary key. Employee can (but doesn't have to) have some *details*, so that table (`employee_detail`) has to have a foreign key constraint column which references primary key column of the `employee` table.

Furthermore, saying that every employee can have only one detail (i.e. one-to-one relationship) is also wrong. Why wouldn't I have 5 detail records?

Something like this (simplified, using Oracle syntax; I don't use your database, but the principle is just the same):

```
SQL> create table employee
  2    (id_emp     number       constraint pk_empl primary key,
  3     first_name varchar2(10) not null,
  4     last_name  varchar2(10) not null
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create table employee_detail
  2    (id_det     number       constraint pk_det primary key,
  3     id_emp     number       constraint fk_det_emp references employee (id_emp),
  4     hobby      varchar2(10)
  5    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

As of "mapping in Java", sorry - I can't help about it, I don't know Java.